# Obtaining street name from postal code - Canada

Tags: php, jquery, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I would like to know if anyone has been able to map a postal code to a street name in Canada.

Canada Post does this in their website through their systems. I tried submitting an AJAX POST request to their servers, but after inspecting the POST request that is sent using their website, I realized that they send the postal code and other special variables.

I tried using Google's geocoding service, but they only return City, Province and Country when querying by Postal Code.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't several street names map to a postcode?

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought... try the reverse

Instead of finding the street name for a postal code... because there are many within the same postal code.

find the postal codes for each street name

In Canada, at least the first 3 should be the same... then sort

It should be easy to find a list of street names within any city

ex. http://cartographic.info/ca_street/show.php?p=ont&t=City%20of%20Ottawa

I hope this helps

I am currently trying to create the same for Ottawa Ontario

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Marcel is correct in his comments. By their very nature, postal codes (in most countries that I know of, at least) are bounded regions in which are usually many streets, sometimes other political boundaries, too.

I'm curious how the Canada Post website is able to magically know the street name from a single postal code. Where is the interface located (URL)? What data are you passing in, and what other variables is it sending? Posting these things will make it easier to answer your question more directly.

I work at [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) where we perform US and international address validation. From what I know, as narrow as you can get with only a postal code is *maybe* a city block, floor of a building, or corporation (if it's a unique/custom postal code) -- that's if you have the fully-expanded postal code (in the US, it's called ZIP+4). Canadian post might be different, though.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum requirements are street number and postal code.  Even then there could be multiple street matches that would need to be presented to the end user for selection.

Greg, mentions a good point, but may not be possible if you only know the postal code.  On the flip side, a street can have many postal codes as well and not necessary have the same first half for all of them (think of really long streets).

You can use Curl to post a postal code to 'find an address' and get a listing of results to parse through.  Make sure you pass appropriate fields to the page though (ie. hidden fields from form submission page).